# docker service inside a LXC container: unable to apply RC_ULIMIT settings

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, ulimit

I have a Debian hypervisor in which I ran a LXC Alpine 3.14 container. In the Alpine container, I would like to install a docker service. Alpine provides a docker package, but starting the docker service raises this error:

```
$ sudo service docker start
sh: error setting limit: Operation not permitted
 * docker: unable to apply RC_ULIMIT settings
 * Starting Docker Daemon ...
```

Is the problem on the hypervisor or the container? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [FAQ](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/#faq) mentions it, I had to enable container nesting:

```
lxc config set <container> security.nesting true
```